# How can I filter out records by selected dates in PHP CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, date, filter

I'm trying to draw a graph with reports of clients and I would like to filter out multiple days of stores being closed, because of non-commercial day. I also have a filter date from and to.

```
if( $dateFrom != null ) :
        $dateFrom .= ' 00:00:01';
        $this->db->where('created >=', $dateFrom);
    endif;
    if( $dateTo != null ) :
        $dateTo .= ' 23:59:59';
        $this->db->where('created <=', $dateTo);
    endif;
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to add an additional filter of multiple days. So I currently have something like this, but it does not work.

```
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2020-01-25 23:59:59'"); 
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-01-26 00:00:01' AND '2020-04-05 23:59:59'"); 
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-04-06 00:00:01' AND '2020-04-25 23:59:59'");
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-04-26 00:00:01' AND '2020-06-27 23:59:59'");
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-06-28 00:00:01' AND '2020-08-29 23:59:59'");
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-08-30 00:00:01' AND '2020-12-12 23:59:59'");
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-12-13 00:00:01' AND '2020-12-19 23:59:59'");
$this->db->where("created BETWEEN '2020-12-20 00:00:01' AND '2020-12-31 23:59:59'");
```

So I'm just trying to figure out how to filter out days additionally to a set filter from a date and to a date.

Is there maybe a workaround to this or any fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure this one out myself.
I added "NOT BETWEEN" and then added the days that I wanted to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your exceptional dates in an array like this:

```
$exceptions = ['2020-04-26', '2020-04-27']; // And so on
```

Then capture/define your date range:

```
$dateFrom = $some_source_of_data;
$dateTo = $some_source_of_data2;
```

Then:

```
$this->db->where("DATE(created) BETWEEN DATE('{$dateFrom}') AND DATE('{$dateTo}')"); 
$this->db->where("DATE(created) NOT IN (".implode(',', $exceptions).")");
```